# Traducir modelos de Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Django 3.1.7 y me topé con la necesidad de traducir un modelo a español ya que me pareció lógico que si el usuario predeterminado está en inglés, y siguiendo algún "estándar de escritura de código escalable" debería escribir todos los modelos en inglés y utilizar librerías de traducción para traducir al idioma predeterminado.

El problema es que se ve así:
[image]

Mi código era este:

```py
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    """
    Rubro
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Gracias a otras preguntas en S.O. (en inglés) que encontré, intenté algo así:

```py
name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), max_length=100, unique=True)
description = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Description'), max_length=500)
```

Pero no logré traducir nada; cabe destacar que dentro del archivo "settings.py" principal cambié el `LANGUAGE_CODE` a `es-ES` y aún así no muestra ningún cambio.

¿Cómo debo traducir los modelos y de más?

Comment: Lo que quieres no es traducir la página?

Comment: Sí, pero no lo logro...

Comment: Puedes leer la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/)

Comment: Ya la leí, lo que no encontré fue cómo traducir los modelos en la página de administración, de modo que no quede "Añadir category"

Answer (score 0):

te comento para poder cambiar el nombre de los apps en el admin necesitas definir los verbose en la clase meta de tu modelo, por ejemplo:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    """
    Rubro
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Categoria')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Categorias')
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que solo vas a utilizar un idioma para el proyecto (si vas a utilizar varios idiomas entramos en otras preguntas).

Por una parte, para mostrar las etiquetas de cada campo de forma más “amigable”, se puede definir el parámetro `verbose_name="nombre amigable del campo"`.

Por otra parte, para mostrar el modelo en la administración de forma amigable, se añade ese parámetro (`verbose_name`) y, si el plural no se forma añadiendo una s al final del nombre del modelo, se define también la forma plural con `verbose_name_plural`.

Para tu modelo sería:

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    """
    Rubro
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # no necesario, se crea automáticamente
    name = models.CharField("nombre", max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField("descripción", max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "rubro"
```

Si estuviéramos utlizando campos que no permitan definir directamente el nombre en el primer parámetro (como sí pasa con Charfield, por eso es suficiente poner ahí la cadena de texto), tendríamos:

```
class PaperProperties(models.Model):
    grammage = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="gramaje")
    color = models.ChoiceField(COLOR_CHOICES, verbose_name="color")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "propiedades del papel"
        verbose_name_plural = "propiedades de los papeles"
```

Si vas a utilizar más de un idioma, entonces es necesario asegurarte que tienes activo el middleware de traducción:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    …
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',  # Si no está, no hay traducción
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    …
]
```

Espero haber ayudado.